# How to change the method of quartile computation that Seaborn uses to draw boxplots?

Tags: seaborn

Suppose `df` is a variable assigned a `pandas` DataFrame object, whose collection of numeric columns includes one that is titled `C`.

The following question assumes that, when executing the call

`seaborn.boxplot(data = df, y = 'C')`

Seaborn invokes either `numpy.quantile` or `numpy.percentile` in order to determine where w.r.t. the y-axis to draw the lower and the upper sides of the box as well as the median line.

Now, `numpy.quantile` (and the same applies to `numpy.percentile`) has a parameter called `method` by which the method of computation of the quantile can be chosen from a list of at least 12 alternatives, as listed in [the `numpy.quantile` documentation page](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html). A different choice of method can yield a different output, in other words different numbers can be identified as the `q`th quartile of the same list of data points depending on which of these methods is used to compute the `q`th quartile.

How can I make Seaborn's `boxplot` function employ a different method of quartile computation than the default one?

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with a convoluted, but effective, way to accomplish the desired effect.

The key is to define the following function `establish_percentile_method`. This function has two mandatory parameters, and it returns a value. The mandatory parameters are:

- `method` - a string, one of the possible legitimate arguments that can be passed to `numpy.percentile`'s `method` parameter. For further details, [see the `numpy.percentile` documentation page](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html).
- `og_percentile` - a function object, which should act exactly like the `percentile` function as documented in the `numpy` documentation.

`establish_percentile_method` changes the `numpy` library's `percentile` variable to point to a function that acts almost exactly as documented for `percentile` in the `numpy` documentation, except that its method of computation is `method`.

The return value is a function that acts like `percentile` as described in the `numpy` documentation.

```
def establish_percentile_method(method, og_percentile):
  def new_percentile(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['method'] = method
    return og_percentile(*args, **kwargs)
  np.percentile = new_percentile
  return og_percentile
```

Now you can use the function just defined to change the default method that `numpy.percentile` uses to calculate percentiles, and as a consequence affect every function that invokes `numpy.percentile`, such as `pandas.describe()` or `seaborn.boxplot(...)`.

```
import numpy as np

def establish_percentile_method(method, og_percentile):
  def new_percentile(*args, **kwargs):
    if 'method' not in kwargs:
      kwargs['method'] = method
    return og_percentile(*args, **kwargs)
  np.percentile = new_percentile
  return og_percentile

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1], [2], [3], [4]], columns = ['C'])
print(df) # Or, better, simply df, if you work in an interactive environment such as Google Colab.
df.describe()
sns.boxplot(data = df, y = 'C')

og_percentile = establish_percentile_method('inverted_cdf', np.percentile)
df.describe()
sns.boxplot(data = df, y = 'C')

establish_percentile_method('averaged_inverted_cdf', og_percentile)
df.describe()
sns.boxplot(data = df, y = 'C')

 np.percentile = og_percentile
 df.describe()
 sns.boxplot(data = df, y = 'C')
```